# Bekenstein bound and black hole

Tags: black-holes, quantum-information, astrophysics, entropy, information

I'm confused with this sentence from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound):

> "Upon exceeding the Bekenstein bound a storage medium would collapse into a black hole."

Does that mean "the storage medium will **become** a black hole". Is it just a metaphor? If it is correct, can a human brain become a black hole? (Suppose that the brain's data exceeds the Bekenstein Bound)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the storage medium will *become* a black hole. It is not a metaphor.

A human brain will never become a black hole because it cannot get anywhere near the Bekenstein bound. The bound for a brain is on the order of $10^{42}$ bits, but there are only about $10^{28}$ atoms in an entire human body. So there is no need to worry, if you were worried about this.